# How do I access the elements of a slice object in python

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I'm using scipy.ndimage.label and scipy.ndimage.find_objects to find things in an image.  It returns an array of slices.  I am trying to get the coordinates of the object out of the slice but can't seem to find a way to get inside the slice object.  Here is a simple example:

```
a = 1
b = 2
c = 13
d = 47
j = slice(a,b,None)
k = slice(c,d,None)
x = (j, k)

print(x)
print(x[0])
print(x[0].indices(2))
print(x[1].indices(2))
```

Output is:

```
(slice(1, 2, None), slice(13, 47, None))
slice(1, 2, None)
(1, 2, 1)
(2, 2, 1)
```

Basically I am looking for the ability to get the values for a, b, c, and d if I'm only given the slice tuple x.  I thought indices would get me on the way but I'm not understanding it's behavior.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Are you looking for the `start`, `stop` and `step` properties?

```
>>> s = slice(1, 2, 3)
>>> s.start
1
>>> s.stop
2
>>> s.step
3
```

`slice.indices` computes the start/stop/step for the indices that would be accessed for an iterable with the input length.  So,

```
>>> s = slice(-1, None, None)
>>> s.indices(30)
(29, 30, 1)
```

Which means that you would take item 29 from the iterable.  It is able to be conveniently combined with `xrange` (or `range`):

```
for item in range(*some_slice.indices(len(sequence))):
    print(sequence[item])
```

As a concrete example:

```
>>> a = range(30)
>>> for i in a[-2:]:
...   print(i)
... 
28
29
>>> s = slice(-2, None, None)
>>> for ix in range(*s.indices(len(a))):
...   print(a[ix])
... 
28
29
```

Comment: Yes it was the start, stop, step attributes I was looking for.  Thank you kindly!  Google-fu fails when the terms are so common (like slice).

Comment: @DaveH -- When google fails you, you can always try the builtin `help`:  `help(slice)`.  That at least lists the data descriptors `start`, `stop`, `step`...

Comment: Is there any way to convert slices (with all the slice object(s) they contain) to  a big numpy.array?

Comment: May be it is not comment material, anyway I kind a think it can be related.
`slices_array = np.asarray(slices)` following with `xInd = np.array([(x.start, x.stop-1) for x in slices_array[:,2]])` gives the start and end of all slices. However I can use directly something like `slices_array[:,2].start` and collect the same information. May be it is more general question, can I deconstruct object `slice`, and get a list of lists or list of numpy array or vice versa?

Comment: I'm still not sure that I understand what the list of lists (or numpy array) is supposed to contain.  e.g. if I have a list of slices:  `[slice(1, 10, 1), slice(None, None, None)]`, what would the expected list of lists (or numpy array) look like?